# Java classpath issue with mingw32

Tags: classpath

The mingw32 shell doesn't take in account my CLASSPATH ':' separator: it can just accept one path, and if I put a second, java fails with a NoClassDefFoundError.

I think this is specific to MINGW.

What do you think  ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a semicolon?  I'm not afmiliar with mingw32... but that "w32" kinda hints at a Windows format.

Comment: Yes, semicolon is interpreted, as in *nix, as a command terminator, so it doesn't work...

Comment: I have put a ; like this paht1';'path2';'path3 and it works. Thx